Derivative of scalar function in xCoba
I want to compute the Laplacian of a scalar field around some curved background using xCoba
CD[-\[Alpha]]@CD[\[Alpha]]@\[CapitalPsi][t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]

where CD is the covariant derivative for the background metric g, and \[CapitalPsi] is the predefined scalar function. The above code solves it successfully but I want a cross-check using partial derivative:
$$\nabla^\alpha\nabla_\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\alpha(\sqrt{-g}\,g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta)$$
1/SqgDet*PDCoord[-\[Mu]]@(SqgDet*g[\[Mu], \[Nu]]*PDCoord[-\[Nu]]@\[CapitalPsi][t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]])

where SqgDet is the square root of the metric determinant. It doesn't work. The output is not a scalar but something like 
I guess it's because the derivative of the scalar function is not a CTensor, say PDCoord[-\[Nu]]@\[CapitalPsi][t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]] can not be contracted to another CTensor. What should I do?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.
Full code here:
<< xAct`xTensor`
<< xAct`xCoba`
xAct`xCoba`$LargeComponentSize = 
  10000;(* This is to make sure expressions are displayed *)
DefManifold[M4, 4, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Rho], \[Sigma], \[Mu], \
\[Nu], \[Lambda]}]
DefChart[Coord, M4, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}, 
 ChartColor -> Green]
DefConstantSymbol /@ {M, a};
DefScalarFunction /@ {\[CapitalPsi]};
$Assumptions = And[
  {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]} \[Element] Reals,
  a > 0,
  M > 0,
  0 <= \[Theta][] <= Pi,
  0 <= \[Phi][] < 2 Pi
  ]
g = CTensor[{{-((a^2 - 2 M r[] + r[]^2 - a^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2)/(
      r[]^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)), 0, 
     0, -((2 a M r[] Sin[\[Theta][]]^2)/(
      r[]^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2))}, {0, (
     r[]^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)/(a^2 - 2 M r[] + r[]^2), 0, 
     0}, {0, 0, r[]^2 + a^2  Cos[\[Theta][]]^2, 
     0}, {-((2 a M r[] Sin[\[Theta][]]^2)/(
      r[]^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)), 0, 0, (
     Sin[\[Theta][]]^2 ((a^2 + r[]^2)^2 - 
        a^2 (a^2 + r[] (-2 M + r[])) Sin[\[Theta][]]^2))/(
     r[]^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)}}, {-B, -B}];
SetCMetric[g, Coord, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]
CD = CovDOfMetric[g];
(*Laplacian of Psi*)
CD[-\[Alpha]]@
  CD[\[Alpha]]@\[CapitalPsi][t[], 
    r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]] // FullSimplify
(*Corss Check*)
SqgDet = Sqrt[-Det[g[[1]]]];
1/SqgDet   PDCoord[-\[Mu]]@(SqgDet   g[\[Mu], \[Nu]]  \
PDCoord[-\[Nu]]@\[CapitalPsi][t[], 
       r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]) // FullSimplify


Note that you defined the metric with bases {-B, -B}. I think you mean {-Coord, -Coord}.
The output you get has a mixture of expanded and non-expanded basis vectors. Use FromBasisExpand to have a single common form. Then the two computations (call them lap1 and lap2) will coincide. This should give zero:
lap1 - FromBasisExpand[lap2] // Simplify


Yeah, "B" should be "Coord" because I mix-used codes of different versions. It does work using FromBasisExpand[]. Thank you!
